# Expected an indented block and unexpected indent error at same time

Tags: python, rstudio

I am writing this function to tokenize text for machine learning:

```
def tokenization(text):
    tokens = re.split('\s+', text)
    return tokens
```

When I run this, I get two indentation errors:

```
>>> def tokenization(text):
...   tokens = re.split('\s+', text)
IndentationError: expected an indented block (<string>, line 1)
IndentationError: unexpected indent (<string>, line 1)
>>>   return tokens
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function (<string>, line 1)
>>>   
>>>
```

I have tried rewriting the function, removing/adding spaces indentations.  Other similar functions work fine.

How can I fix this?

I am running Python in RStudio.

***edit*** I had originally added my code into this question with a missing indentation.  I have edited above to what I believe the code should be.  This code still returns the same error.

Comment: Indentation is  4 spaces from zero to four.

Comment: Change editor / IDE? PyCharm is the best Python IDE, but there are other editors for Python too. R studio is good for R, not sure how good it is for writing python code.

Comment: thanks, I would love to use PyCharm (its what I personally use) but this is for work and I am having problems running it.  RStudio is actually changing its name to Posit to be more Python orientated: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2022/07/posit-why-rstudio-is-changing-its-name/?utm_source=phpList&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=R-bloggers-daily&utm_content=HTML

Comment: @toyotaSupra thanks, I had tried that, but added the code to this question with a missing indentation.  I have corrected the question above, as I still have the same error

Comment: maybe put code in file and run as file - instead of using python console.

Answer (score -1):

Probably your indentation is not a multiple of 4.
I am not sure if you can install plugins in R-Studio, but there is a
Plugin for VSC and Pycharm called rainbow indent, which would help you catch such errors.

Comment: Python doesn't require that indentation be a multiple of four. The PEP 8 style guide _recommends_ using 4-spaces indentation, but Python is completely happy as long as you are consistent within each level of indentation. You can even mix and match if you really want to (e.g. use tabs to indent the body of a loop, then two spaces for the next loop, then 17 spaces in the next one...), though it's a terrible idea.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why, but adding an 'r' in front of the string in the pattern works:

```
def tokenization(text):
    tokens = re.split(r'\s+', text)
    return tokens
```

Comment: But that code is also fine (as far as IndentationErrors are concerned) without the `r` - that isn't what makes the difference. Were you able to reproduce the error that OP got?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).